# Add pandas dataframes to a dict

Tags: pandas

I want to add a dataframes to a dict but I'm getting a `KeyError` when I do a join to generate each dataframe. Basically, each df is created by the join of two others, then I want to add all the dataframes to a dict but it gives a KeyError on the join key. Here's the code

```
    symbols = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
    df_dict = {}
    for symbol in symbols:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(symbol_to_path(symbol)+'.tsv', sep='\t', header = 7, na_values=['nan'])
        df2 = pd.read_csv(symbol_to_path(symbol)+'MM'+'.tsv', sep='\t', header = 0, na_values=['nan'])
        df = df1.join(df2,on="Length",rsuffix='_right')    
        df['Mp'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
        df_dict[symbol] = df
```

So df1 reads a .tsv file called e.g. 'A1.tsv' and `df2` reads one called e.g. ' A1MM.tsv' then `df` joins them but  when `len(symbols)` >1 it gives `KeyError: 'Length'`. Btw, the left join that I'm doing is what I need given the files.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your dictionary. `on="Length"` giving a key error meaning that that column does not exist. Check your data and see if the column actually exists. If it does, check your delimiters. Maybe you need sep='\s+' instead of `\t`.

Comment: You're right. It's actually one of the files that had missing data on some columns. Thanks!